# iOS - UITextField: extend the bottom line for ANY resolution

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitextfield

I created a UITextFiled with a **bottom line** using this:

```
let Bottomline CALayer = ()
bottomLine.frame CGRect = (x: 0, y: usernameTextField.frame.height-7, width: usernameTextField.frame.width, height: 1)
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
TextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.none
TextField.layer.addSublayer (Bottomline)
```

and the result of an iPhone 6 (right) is this:

[image]

Ok.

✄------------------------

> The problem is to run the same application on a Pro iPad, because the
>   bottom line does not extend following the UITextField, but is shorter

This is the result on iPad Pro:

[image]

I do not understand why the bottom line does not follow the UITextField. When I called the bottom line I defined as:

```
bottomLine.frame CGRect = (x: 0, y: usernameTextField.frame.height-7, width: usernameTextField.frame.width, height: 1)
```

I have specified that the length of the line at the bottom must be:

```
width: usernameTextField.frame.width
```

**What's the problem?**

> EDIT 1: The contrains are correct, because the UITextField adapts to
>   all types of resolution

[image]

***EDIT:2 Thanks Matt! Now work!!!***

[image]

Comment: in which func are you setting the bottomLine's frame?

Comment: @dvdblk in viewDidLoad

Comment: Geometry of a view is not set in `viewDidLoad()`. You should not be doing it in that func. Try setting it up in `viewWillAppear()`.

Comment: @dvdblk i tried, unfortunately i get the same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand why the bottom line does not follow the UITextField

Because it's a layer. Layers do not automatically change size when their superlayer (the text field) changes size.

So, you need to redraw the bottom line every time the text field changes size.

At the moment, though, you are configuring the "bottom line" layer in `viewDidLoad`. So you are basing it on the `frame` that the text field has at that moment. But the text field has not yet attained its real size. Then it *does* change size, and meanwhile your "bottom line" layer just sits there — so now it is the wrong size.

An easy solution is to *subclass* UITextField and redraw the line every time `layoutSubviews` is called:

```
class MyTextField : UITextField {
    var lineLayer : CALayer?
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.lineLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height-7, width: self.bounds.width, height: 1)
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
        self.lineLayer = bottomLine
    }
}
```

If your text field is a MyTextField, it will behave exactly as you desire.

Comment: hmm, i understand the problem, but i can't understand how I can solve it

Comment: @matt so the proper place to set geometry things up should be `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` right? This however doesn't work for op for some reason.

Comment: @matt see the edit in the post, now it works! Thank you very much!